# Expression to extract zips of particular format

Tags: regex

I have below scenario,if zip_code is present as:

WS1 1 then extract and make it WS11

WS11 2 then extract and make it WS11

```
Below I wrote logic, but it's not satisfying all the scenarios:

CASE 
    WHEN ${ID} = 3 THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(zip_code)) = 5 THEN UPPER(zip_code)
            ELSE UPPER(REPLACE(TRIM(zip_code), ' ', ''))
        END
 AS zip_code

Also tried below:

CASE 
            WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(zip_code)) = 5 THEN UPPER(zip_code)
            WHEN INSTR(zip_code, ' ') > 0 AND LENGTH(TRIM(zip_code)) = 6 
            THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(zip_code, 1, INSTR(zip_code, ' ')))
            ELSE UPPER(SUBSTRING(TRIM(zip_code), 1, 5))
        END
 zip_code
```

Comment: What language is this? I see some string replacement functions but nothing that looks like a regex pattern.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.